# How can I create a non-blocking GUI with cmd2 and wxPython?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, wxpython, wxwidgets

#### How can I create non-blocking `wxPython` GUI windows from a `cmd2` interpreter command even though both the interpreter and `wx.App` must be run on the main thread?

---

I am creating a command-line interpreter in Python 3.x using the `cmd2` module. One command in my interpreter will allow me to create a "non-blocking" `wxPython` GUI window with a countdown timer that runs in a separate thread. It needs to run separately from the main interpreter thread because otherwise it will prevent entering additional commands while the timer runs.

When I try to use the `wxTimer` object to allow my GUI to update its progress bar and check the remaining time, I get the following error:

```
wx._core.wxAssertionError: C++ assertion "wxThread::IsMain()" failed at ..\..\src\common\timerimpl.cpp(60) in wxTimerImpl::Start(): timer can only be started from the main thread
```

Any attempt to start the timer breaks the code. For example, the following simple code does not work:

```
import wx
import threading
import cmd2

class TimerFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, time):
        super().__init__(None, title=str(time), size=(300, 300))
        self.InitUI()

    def InitUI(self):
        self.timer = wx.Timer(self, 1)
        self.timer.Start(100)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER, self.OnTimer, id=1)
        self.Show()

    def OnTimer(self, event):
        print("Updating")

class Interpreter(cmd2.Cmd):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.app = wx.App()

    def do_timer(self, _):
        threading.Thread(target=self.createTimer, args=(self.app,)).start()

    def createTimer(self, app):
        TimerFrame("Window Title")
        app.MainLoop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Interpreter().cmdloop()
```

Note that commenting out the line containing `timer.Start(100)` allows windows to be created in separate threads successfully, but they lack the necessary `Timer` functionality.

---

Other things I have tried that do not work:

- Creating the `wx.App` in the new thread instead of passing it (results in the same error but for the `MainLoop` rather than `Timer`)
- Creating the `wx.App` in the main thread and running its `MainLoop` there (blocks the command line from accepting further commands)
- Running the interpreter command loop in a separate thread (complains that the `cmdloop` must be run from the main thread)

Comment: As for why it dies, the timer uses the timer signal and python restricts signals to the main thread.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The docs have a section on [Integrating cmd2 with event loops](https://cmd2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integrating.html#integrating-cmd2-with-event-loops):

> Many Python concurrency libraries involve or require an event loop which they are in control of such as `asyncio`, `gevent`, `Twisted`, etc.

While this is specifically talking about networking-focused event loops, it's actually the same issue with GUI event loops like wx's.

The tl;dr is that instead of calling `cmdloop()`, blocking the entire main thread until the interpreter exits, you just call `preloop()`, and then you repeatedly call `onecmd()` (or `onecmd_plus_hooks()` or `runcmd_plus_hooks()`, as appropriate) from a `wx` callback.

In other words, you drive the `cmd2` event loop from the `wx` one, so the `wx` loop can just take over the thread.

---

`wx` also has a way of driving its event loop manually. See [`wx.EventLoopBase`](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.EventLoopBase.html) and related classes. (There's probably some good example code out there similar to the code in the `cmd2` docs, but you'd have to search for it.) The idea is pretty much the same: instead of running the `wx` loop and blocking the thread forever, you manually create a `wx.EventLoop` and `wx.EventLoopActivator`, and then you repeatedly call `while loop.Pending(): loop.Dispatch()` (and probably `app.ProcessIdle()`) from the `cmd2` event loop.

In other words, you drive the `wx` event loop from the `cmd2` one, so the `cmd2` loop can just take over the thread.

---

If neither of those work for you, you can probably use [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) instead of `threading`. That way, both event loops are running in the main thread—but one of them is just running in the main thread of a child process.

That can be a problem for GUI apps, so putting `wx` in the child process may not work (or, worse, may work on some platforms/setups but not others, or may work but mysteriously fail every so often…), but `cmd2` presumably only needs to see stdin/stdout/tty, so it probably will work.

Comment: I ended up using `multiprocessing` for running the fairly simple Timer GUI in a child process (mostly to avoid large code refactoring). I have tested on Windows and OS X, and the performance is consistent. Thanks for the speedy and comprehensive response!

Comment: @jstrieb My main worry was OS X (the application-vs.-process distinction, GUI APIs that hide communication with a window server, sandboxing stuff, etc.); if it works for you there, you should be fine.